# Getting a TypeError at / 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, function, filter, django-views

I keep getting this error ('function' object is not iterable) after having added a new def function in my .views file, any thoughts on what the problem could be?

The goal with this is to filter querysets with checkboxes.

Here's my views.py function:

```
def FilterView(request):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    ptag = request.GET.get('ptag')

    if ptag == 'on':
        qs = qs.filter(ptag='')

    qs = filter(request)
    context = {
        'queryset': qs
    }
    return render(request, "partials/search_form.html", context)
```

And in my urls:

```
from search.views import HomeView, FilterView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), FilterView),
]
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: please include your whole stack trace

Comment: What is `qs = filter(request)` supposed to do?

Comment: Why are you using `url(...)` in `urlpatterns`?  I believe `path(...)` is recommended.

Comment: Why are you passing both `HomeView.as_view()` and `FilterView` as arguments to your root url?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, really appreciated! And sorry guys, I'm still new to this, but willing to learn. :) I'm using url(...) instead of path(...) because I'm on Django 1.10.5 version since I need to use Haystack and this urlpattern comes with it as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense. You are passing both your `HomeView` and your `FilterView` to a single `url()`, and you are running the builtin `filter` function on a request object? Here should be a working example, minus the unexplained `filter()`:

`urls.py`

```
from search.views import HomeView, FilterView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^$', FilterView, name='filter'),
    ...
]
```

`views.py`

```
def FilterView(request):
    ptag = request.GET.get('ptag', '')
    qs = Product.objects.all() if ptag != 'on' else Product.objects.filter(ptag='')

    #qs = filter(request)  # What is this even trying to do?
    context = {
        'queryset': qs
    }
    return render(request, "partials/search_form.html", context)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I really appreciate that! What about inserting this function inside a class like this?                                                                                                       I've tried it and I don't get the error anymore! Here's the urls:                       
url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()

Comment: And the code in the views file:                                                                                                      ` class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    def FilterView(request):
          ptag = request.GET.get('ptag', '')
          qs = Product.objects.all() if ptag != 'on' else Product.objects.filter(ptag='')

          context = {
              'queryset': qs
          }
          return render(request, "partials/search_form.html", context)`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in both homeview and filterview. You need to choose one.

in urls.py
change

```
url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), FilterView)
```

to

```
url(r'^$', Filterview)
```